# How to preload a entire website like Gmail?

Tags: php, jquery, user-interface

How to preload the entire website like gmail does? How to show this in progress bar? What are the mechanisms used to get this effect?

I can use jquery, jquery UI, php. Will this be enought to create this?

Answer (score 5):

I'm quite sure Gmail is built using the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/), which essentially means that your whole application is contained in JavaScript files.. in fact the initial page source of Gmail is practically empty.
This post will probably help: [GMail like file upload progress bar with GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624891/gmail-like-file-upload-progress-bar-with-gwt)

Comment: I was looking for more of Jquery Solution. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

idea behind showing progress bar while page is loading....simply start loading bar and hide when `$(document).ready();` All the others things after that are made with `hashbang / hashtag`. [Here](http://www.amitpatil.me/create-gmail-like-app-using-html5-history-api-and-hashbang/) is exactly what you are looking for