# 2 questions about HTTP file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

1. Is it possible to use jquery .ajax() call to post a file to the server and setup a callback function when the upload is done?
2. Is it possible to get the progress of the uploading process(as GMail) using any possilbe method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. not via ajax, but via hidden iframe
   check this out
   [Gmail like file upload with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710852/gmail-like-file-upload-with-jquery)
2. yes, you'll need custom logic on server side.
   [GMail like file upload progress bar with GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624891/gmail-like-file-upload-progress-bar-with-gwt)

there are plenty of q&a's on stackoverflow on the topic
try searching for them

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it natively in all browsers so you have to use a workaround like uploading through a hidden iframe, or using flash (at least for the browsers that dont support it). There are [several jquery plugins that implement ajax uploads](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/).